# How to retrieve a tool window's position in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

In the Visual Studio extension I'm developing, I provide a custom tool window.

I'm trying to find out if the user has the tool window docked to a side (left/right/top/bottom) or if it is floating.
Is there a way to calculate the current position of my tool window and is there an event to know after a user has completed moving it?

Some background: I'm developing the CodeStream extension for Visual Studio. There is functionality that when a user selects code we show three circle buttons in the CodeStream tool window (it's actually a webview) to provide some actions. When the CodeStream panel is docked to the right, the 3 buttons are on the left side of the panel and this is correct.

But, if a user moves the CodeStream panel to the left side of screen or elsewhere, I'd like to be able to know that so I can direct our webview to move the 3 buttons to the *right* side of the screen. I've provided two screenshots below.

We also have a VSCode extension and I've implemented similar logic there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-tool-window?view=vs-2019#set-the-default-position-for-the-tool-window) and [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b400b696-744c-4090-bd04-4a4ef8cd41d0/vs-custom-tool-window-how-to-set-currently-active-document?forum=vsx).

Comment: thanks @HiGuy, I know about setting its default position/style, but I'm more looking for these things: 1) an event that is raised when a user moves it 2) how to figure out where it is in the editor (left/right/top/bottom/floating)

Comment: I am afraid that you can not  get what you want so far. And I will give you any feedback if I find any ideas.

Comment: Once you had the answer, what would you do with it? There's a few different options you may have depending on your final goal.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I've added some additional background (and screenshots)

Comment: Maybe it is quite difficultly so far. The easiest way is that when you install this extension, manually adjust the position.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [IVsWindowFrame.GetFramePos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivswindowframe.getframepos?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-ivswindowframe-getframepos(microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-vssetframepos()-system-guid@-system-int32@-system-int32@-system-int32@-system-int32@)) method:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
...
ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

if (Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Interop.IVsUIShell)) is Interop.IVsUIShell shellService)
{
    shellService.GetToolWindowEnum(out var toolWindows);

    foreach (Interop.IVsWindowFrame frame in ComUtilities.EnumerableFrom(toolWindows))
    {
        frame.GetProperty((int)VsFramePropID.DocView, out var docView);
        if (docView?.GetType().FullName == "MyNamespace.MyToolWindow")
        {
            frame.GetFramePos(out var pos, out var guid, out int px, out int py, out int pcx, out int pcy);

            // Do something

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have not explored the usage of the values provided by `GetFramePos`.  The docs say "Returns the position of the window," so presumably they are useful for that purpose.

(There may be a more expedient way to obtain the target `Interop.IVsWindowFrame` than enumerating all the tool windows as in the above example... that's just what I was doing when I discovered this method.)